# How to redirect to custom page after login in panels?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-panels

I have '/front' page is homepage in Drupal.'/front' is realized by panel page. I want to redirect to another page after logging in panels template for '/from'.

Comment: Hi Welcome to SO, Please read guidelines of posting questions and give more details. Also please include minimum working example if required

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple modules that let you redirect users after logging in (or out). For example Login Destination: https://www.drupal.org/project/login_destination

> The Login Destination module allows you to customize the destination that a user is redirected to after logging in, registering to the site (7.x), using a one-time login link or logging out (7.x)